# Не происходит событие onload если была нажата ссылка

Tags: javascript, html

На странице есть ссылка с телефоном в url. При нажатии на нее в chrome, firefox появляется диалог, позволяющий выбрать приложение для ее открытия (если до этого не был установлен чекбокс "запомнить выбор").

Если нажать на эту ссылку до полной загрузки страницы, событие window.onload не произойдет.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            alert('onload')
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="tel:1234">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

С чем это связано? Как обойти это поведение? Есть спецификация, описывающая этот момент?

Answer (score 2):

> Событие `onload` на `window` ([`window.onload`](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded#window-onload)) срабатывает, когда
>   загружается вся страница, включая ресурсы на ней – стили, картинки,
>   ифреймы и т.п.

То есть, страница еще не загружена, а вы выполнили другое действие. Попробуйте заменить `window.onload` на [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  alert('DOM fully loaded and parsed')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="tel:1234">link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

> Событие [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) происходит когда весь HTML был полностью
>   загружен и пройден парсером, не дожидаясь окончания загрузки таблиц
>   стилей, изображений и фреймов. Значительно отличающееся от него
>   событие load используется для отслеживания только полностью
>   загруженной страницы. Широко распространённой ошибкой является
>   использование load в ситуации когда DOMContentLoaded является более
>   подходящим, будьте внимательны.

Также, в этом источнике есть вот такой пункт (подробнее в ссылках):

> Если вы хотите чтобы DOM был пройден парсером насколько возможно
>   быстро, сразу после запроса пользователем страницы, вы можете
>   попробовать выполнять [JavaScript асинхронно](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) и [оптимизировать загрузку таблиц стилей](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) которые обычно замедляют загрузку документа поскольку загружаясь одновременно "крадут" трафик у основного документа.

Comment: А что, если нужно именно событие **load**? К примеру, в обработчике этого события инициализируется приложение. Если пользователь нажмет на ссылку с href="tel:" до загрузки страницы, то приложение вообще не запустится.

_То есть, страница еще не загружена, а вы выполнили другое действие._
Если ссылка ссылается, к примеру, на якорь, то при ее нажатии подобного не происходит. 

Единственным вариантом вижу только установку обработчика в начале страницы или в head, который будет отлавливать нажатия по таким ссылкам и вызывать **preventDefault()**, а затем в **onload** убирать этот обработчик.

Comment: @VladimirZhdanov, постарайтесь описать задачу более детально. Да, как вы описали с `preventDefault` можно попробовать, но мне кажется это все же будет криво работать. Знаете, можно еще попробовать скрыть по умолчанию ссылки, а когда документ прогружен - показать. Ну, идею вы уловили я думаю. По поводу инициализации приложия, а есть смысл ждать загрузки всей страницы? Может просто в самом начале страницы написать скрипт , который выполнится сразу после того, как анализатор наткнется на него? И никаких `onload` не нужно. А вообще, для такого случая подойдет запуск асинхронного JS.